# How to kill iphone application via command line

Tags: ios, iphone, command-line

I want to kill the application which is running on iphone. So when it the application is killed it comes on the home page.

Is there any command that can be used via terminal?

Comment: How are you accessing your device via terminal-- is it jailbroken?

Comment: no...using idevicedebug and ios-deploy

Comment: i have tried those but no luck

Comment: @ParthParikh Hi, any luck with that? I am looking for the same solution.

Comment: @RoyK use xcrun instruments to install the app....to kill use killall bundleid!

Comment: @ParthParikh Hi Parth, can you elaborate a bit on solution you explained above? May be answer your own question. It will help fellow programmers.

Comment: @ParthParikh what I am not getting is where to call this `killall` at.

Answer (score 0):

i have slightly modified the `ios-deploy` source to support the stop function:

just add a -S option

you could have a try:
https://github.com/fatfatson/ios-deploy